# How to accommodate two sets of NTP servers

Tags: ntp

I have a case where, within one company, half of the devices synchronize to a set of NTP servers (including a GPS based one), and the other one on another set (also including stratum 1 servers).

I would like to understand how to handle such situation, my only real requirement being that everyone has the same time (even if it is not atomic-time grade). Specifically - is there  way to configure the servers so that they take into account the other ones and so that all of them provide a synchronized time?

The NTP FAQ [states](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo-real.htm#Q-NTP-ALGO):

> Just one time source will always be trusted

so I would like this choice to be consistent between the two groups.

Comment: Is pointing them all to a consistent time source not an option? Even if it's a third, as yet unused, time source?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a pool of ntp servers to be used internally (2-5 servers is appropriate in a small organization). Have each of them synchronize to external servers (and other time sources if applicable). Have each of the servers in your pool specify the other servers in your pool as peers.

Finally configure your internal hosts to use the servers in your own pool of ntp servers and never directly use external ntp servers.

Comment: Belated comment. Never provide only two time servers. Consider, if you have only two servers and one starts giving false time, how do your clients know which one is wrong? With only one server everyone remains consistent (even if that consistency is wrong). With more than two the voting algorithms will ignore the false clock.

Comment: @roaima Relevant point, but I think failure of an individual NTP server is a more likely event than a pair of NTP servers giving different results. So I still consider two NTP servers to be a more reliable setup than one, but of course two is less reliable than three.